# Does a football referee have a duty to prevent a team from using more substitutions than they're allowed to?

Tags: rules, football, officiating, substitution

AS Roma lost a game against Spezia in the 2020-21 Coppa Italia because they exceeded the number of substitutions they were allowed to do, mistakenly thinking they could go for a sixth one in extra time.

If the referee had noticed what was about to happen, would he have been required to step in and stop the substitution (***The referee: [...] enforces the Laws of the Game***, Law 5)? Or should he have allowed the substitution to take place, only to caution the players involved immediately after (***For any other offences: [...] the players are cautioned***, Law 3)?

I'm asking because it seems to be "common knowledge" here in Italy that the referee shouldn't actually do anything in a situation like this, essentially allowing the team to be punished by the league after the match has ended, though I have found no evidence supporting this course of action in the IFAB Laws of the Game.

Comment: They can and they should intervene and deny that sub. But I'm not sure, if they have to.